# If [MYSQL QUERY] Is True Then Echo

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, enums, echo

in my MySQL database I have set an ENUM with the values '0' and '1' - if I set the value to '1' the user is a moderator on the website, that all works.

However, I would like it so that if a user had the Moderator Row ENUM set to '1' for an echoed message to appear on the users profile. Would I do this using an if statement?

EXTRA INFO:
The MySQL table is called `Users`
The Row in question is called `Moderator` with the values 0 and 1 - 1 being a moderator.
I am using MySqli queries.

Thank you.

Comment: You could `echo` inside a conditional statement along with `WHERE column=Moderator AND other_column=1` if it meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you should use the `if` statement. I assume you fetch the user's data somewhere, don't you? If not, use a `SELECT` statement to get user's data, then `mysqli_fetch_array()` to fetch it into an array.
And then do (assuming `$row` is your array):

```
if ($row['Moderator'] == 1) {
// Echo your message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL query by itself cannot be `true`. You can test if the returned value is `'1'`.

Something like this should do the job:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT Moderator FROM Users WHERE id = ?');
$query->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']); // Change $_GET['id'] with the user identifier
$query->bind_result($moderator); // You can choose another variable name
$query->execute();
$query->fetch();

if ($moderator == '1') {
    echo "You are a moderator!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. For this you can follow following steps :

1) After successful user login you can store the User data in a object or you an store it in a  array. choice is yours.

2) Now you check the condition that whether the user is moderator or not (Using Obj->column == 1). If it is true then echo the message.